# Javascript add/remove animation class, only animates once

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Trying to build a time picker, that is supposed to animate the change of input. I thought I'd do this by adding and removing an animation class from CSS. The problem is, that it only works the first time.

I tried to set an interval to start with, that removed the class after a certain amount of time, slightly above the animation duration, but that reduced the animation time of the animation with each click, and by the third or fourth click, it no longer animated.

Then I just opted to check if the class existed to start with, remove it to start with, then add it. To make sure it starts from scratch each time. But now it only animates the very first time.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SkriptKiddy/pen/QWLXNNB)

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="uphour"></div>
      <div id="upminute"></div>
      <div id="upampm"></div>
      <div class="animated">
        <div id="hour" data-hour="1">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="animated">
        <div id="minute" data-minute="1">50</div>
      </div>
      <div class="animated">
        <div id="ampm" data-minute="AM">AM</div>
      </div>
      <div id="downhour"></div>
      <div id="downminute"></div>
      <div id="downampm"></div>
      </div>
```

(the data attributes here are not currently in use)

**SCSS:**

```
    $finger: 2cm;
    $smallfinger: .3cm;

    #wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: $finger $finger $finger;
      grid-template-rows: $finger $finger $finger;
      grid-column-gap: $smallfinger;
      grid-row-gap: $smallfinger;
      position:absolute;
      width: 100vw;
      background: #FF00FF;
      height: calc( (#{$finger} * 3) + (#{$smallfinger} * 4) );
      box-sizing: border-box;
      bottom:$finger;
      left:0;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
      align-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      }

    #uphour,
    #upminute,
    #upampm,
    #downhour,
    #downminute,
    #downampm {
      display: flex;
      background: rgba(255,0,0,.4);
      width: $finger;
      height: $finger;
      margin-left: 1vw;
      margin-right: 1vw;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .animated {
      display: flex;
      width: $finger;
      height: $finger;
      margin-left: 1vw;
      margin-right: 1vw;
      border: 1px solid black;
      overflow:hidden;
    }


    #minute, #hour, #ampm {
      display: flex;
      /*background: rgba(255,0,0,.4); for testing of animation only*/
      width: $finger;
      height: $finger;
      border: 0;
      position: relative;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: .8cm;
    }

    .animateStart {
      -webkit-animation-name: downandout; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      animation-name: downandout;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 250ms; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
      animation-duration: 250ms;
      /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1);
    }

    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    @-webkit-keyframes downandout {
      0%   {top: 0; left: 0;}
      10%  {top: 100%; left:0;}
      50%  {top: 100%; left: 100%;}
      90% {top: -100%; left:100%;}
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes downandout {
      0%   {top: 0; left: 0;}
      40%  {top: 100%; left:0;}
      42%  {top: 100%; left: calc(#{$finger} * 2);}
      48% {top: -110%; left: calc(#{$finger} * 2);}
      50% {top: -110%; left:0;}
      100% {top: 0; left:0;}
    }
```

**Javascript:**

```
    var uphourEl = document.getElementById("uphour");
    var downhourEl = document.getElementById("downhour");
    var upminuteEl = document.getElementById("upminute");
    var downminuteEl = document.getElementById("downminute");
    var upampmEl = document.getElementById("upampm");
    var downampmEl = document.getElementById("downampm");

    uphourEl.addEventListener("click", increaseHour);
    downhourEl.addEventListener("click", decreaseHour);
    upminuteEl.addEventListener("click", increaseMinute);
    downminuteEl.addEventListener("click", decreaseMinute);
    upampmEl.addEventListener("click", swapAMPM);
    downampmEl.addEventListener("click", swapAMPM);

    var hourEl = document.getElementById("hour"); 
    var minuteEl = document.getElementById("minute"); 
    var ampmEl = document.getElementById("ampm"); 

    function increaseHour() {
      let value = hourEl.innerHTML;
      if (value > 11) {
          value = 1
      } else  {
        value++;
      }
      hourEl.innerHTML = value;
      console.log(value);
    }

    function decreaseHour() {
      let value = hourEl.innerHTML;
      if (value < 2) {
          value = 12
      } else  {
        value--;
      }
      hourEl.innerHTML = value;
      console.log(value);
    }

    function increaseMinute() {
      let value = minuteEl.innerHTML;
      if (value > 58) {
          value = 0
      } else  {
        value++;
      }
      minuteEl.innerHTML = value;
      console.log(value);
    }

    function decreaseMinute() {
      let value = minuteEl.innerHTML;
      if (value < 1) {
          value = 59
      } else  {
        value--;
      }
      minuteEl.innerHTML = value;
      console.log(value);
    }

    function swapAMPM() {
      let value = ampmEl.innerHTML;
      if (ampmEl.hasAttribute("class")) {
        ampmEl.removeAttribute("class");
      }
      ampmEl.setAttribute("class", "animateStart");
      if (value === "AM") {
          value = "PM";
          ampmEl.innerHTML = value;
          console.log("Changed from AM");
      } else  {
        value = "AM";
        ampmEl.innerHTML = value;
        console.log("Changed from PM");
      }
    }
```

..it's the swapAMPM function (at the end of the Javascript) I'm currently not getting to behave as expected.

Any suggestions on why I am experiencing this behavior? Is there some best practice I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use animation iteration event listener to detect when your animation has ended, and correctly remove your class. for this to work, animation iteration has to be set to infinite. in my changes, i also took advantage of the `classList` property of elements to add/remove the class from the element.

**NOTE: without atleast 1 iteration, the animation iteration event will never fire, and thus the code will not work!**

**EDIT: browser support for `classList` is fairly recent, so if you need to support older browsers you can fall back to a different solution, or add a [classList polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classlist-polyfill)**

**first we, need a function to detect which animation iteration event is supported by the browser:**

```
function whichAnimationEvent(){
  var el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var animations = {
    "animation"      : "animationiteration",
    "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationIteration",
    "MozAnimation"   : "animationiteration",
    "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationIteration"
  };

  for (let t in animations){
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
      return animations[t];
    }
  }
}
```

**next, we need to add an event listener for that event, and when the iteration fires, we remove the class from the element's `classList`, as shown below:**

```
ampmEl.addEventListener(whichAnimationEvent(),function(){
  console.log('ampmEl event listener fired')
  ampmEl.classList.remove('animateStart');
});
```

**next, we change the `swapAMPM` function to use the `add` method of the elements `classList` to add the class before performing the swap, so that it is animated.**

```
function swapAMPM() {
  let value = ampmEl.innerHTML;
  ampmEl.classList.add('animateStart');
  if (value === "AM") {
      value = "PM";
      ampmEl.innerHTML = value;
      console.log("Changed from AM");
  } else  {
    value = "AM";
    ampmEl.innerHTML = value;
    console.log("Changed from PM");
  }
}
```

**finally, we need to update the css to have `infinite` animation-iteration, so that our event will fire.**

```
.animateStart {
  -webkit-animation-name: downandout; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: downandout;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 250ms; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-duration: 250ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1);
}
```

**full working example**

[codepen](https://codepen.io/r3wt/pen/WNeqxeB)

Comment: Cool! I actually stumbled upon that solution yesterday, but I never understood the fakeelement part, and the article I found never mentioned anything about infinite iterations and why it was needed, nor any of the detailed breakdown like you did. Perhaps now I stand a chance of getting it. Can you try to explain the fakeelement part? If you can, I'd appreciate it! I'll mark this as the solution as it seems like the most viable solution in the long run.

Comment: we create the fake element so we can inspect its style properties to see which animation properties it has natively, and thus we reveal which animation iteration events it supports. if using a named element such as `a` or `img` or `div` etc, the properties may or may not be present, but any newly defined element will have all supported properties by default, so that is probably why we use `fakeelement`.

Comment: @Strechingmycompetence i added a note to the answer about `classList` browser support. i forgot to mention earlier that older browsers don't support this

Comment: Nice! That's really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is how you would do in in vanilla

gugateider is right, your gonna need a setTimout, there is AnimationEvent API but its not fully supported.

below is a streamlined approach:

no event listners or collecting IDs needed

#### updated:

- Included a debounce to stop mulitple clicks to the same button
- tweaked timeout (*The timeout is added so that the value changes out of view to give the illusion the numbers are actually rotating, the AnimationEvent cant detect if you are half way through your animation.*)

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="hour" class="unit">
    <div class="plus button" onClick="pressedButton(event);">+</div>
    <div class="value"><div>10</div></div>
    <div class="minus button" onClick="pressedButton(event);">-</div>
  </div>

    <div id="minute" class="unit">
    <div class="plus button"  onClick="pressedButton(event);">+</div>
      <div class="value"><div>36</div></div>
    <div class="minus button"  onClick="pressedButton(event);">-</div>
  </div>

    <div id="meridiem" class="unit">
    <div class="plus button"  onClick="pressedButton(event);">+</div>
      <div class="value"><div>AM</div></div>
    <div class="minus button"  onClick="pressedButton(event);">-</div>
  </div>



</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

.unit {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: grey;

  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

}


.value {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: lightgrey;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.animate {
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: downandout;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  &--reverse {
    animation-direction: reverse;
  }
}




 @keyframes downandout {
   0%  {top: 0}
   50% {top: 50px}
   51% {top: -50px}
   100%  {top: 0}
}
```

```js
debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

pressedButton = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();

  // debouncedFn to stop multiple clicks to the same button
  var debouncedFn = debounce(function() {
    // All the taxing stuff you do
    const target = $event.target;
    const elm = target.parentNode.children[1];

    let direction;

    // clone the element to restart the animation
    const newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
    // add the first animate
    newone.children[0].classList.add("animate");

    // What button was pressed
    if (target.classList.contains("minus")) {
      direction = "down";
    } else {
      direction = "up";
    }

    // direction of animation
    if (direction === "down") {
      newone.children[0].classList.add("animate--reverse");
    } else {
      newone.children[0].classList.remove("animate--reverse");
    }

    // add the new element to the DOM
    elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);

    // change value after half of the animation has completed
    setTimeout(function() {
      switch (target.parentNode.id) {
        case "hour":
        case "minute":
          if (direction === "down") {
            newone.children[0].innerText--;
          } else {
            newone.children[0].innerText++;
          }
          break;

        case "meridiem":
          if (newone.children[0].innerText === "PM") {
            newone.children[0].innerText = "AM";
          } else {
            newone.children[0].innerText = "PM";
          }
      }
    }, 100);
  }, 250);

  // Call my function
  debouncedFn();

};
```

https://codepen.io/eddy14u/pen/VwZJmdW

Comment: This is a very good answer as it streamlines the code greatly and allows all elements to be neatly animated using the same code.the only thing is, instead of `setTimeout` i would use the animation event listeners.

Comment: unfortunately, there is a great flaw in this answer because of the timeouts. continuously clicking the button resets the animation, so multiple clicks results in only incrementing by one, rather than incrementing the number of times pressed as one might expect.

Answer (score 1):

I know setTimeout is not the best option to use in there, but since you're already pretty much done with that you can try replacing the swapAMPM function with the code below:

```
function swapAMPM() {
 let value = ampmEl.innerHTML;
 if (ampmEl.hasAttribute("class")) {
     ampmEl.removeAttribute("class");
 }
 setTimeout( () => { 
     ampmEl.setAttribute("class", "animateStart");
     if (value === "AM") {
      value = "PM";
      ampmEl.innerHTML = value;
      console.log("Changed from AM");
     } else  {
        value = "AM";
        ampmEl.innerHTML = value;
        console.log("Changed from PM");
    } 
 }, 150);
}
```

Comment: Nice! I ended up trying to setTimeout around each of the condition results as I didn't know I could wrap the whole conditional with it, but that's less code so I'll buy! Also, I added a setTimeout around the very first conditional too, and set it to 500 ms, while the one in the second conditional is now set to 300. That way, the div that is animated is out of the visual space before changing, and changed by the time it enters the visual space again.

Answer (score 0):

in your function `swapAMPM` in the `if statement`, you try to remove an atribute, which doesn't make much cense, because you immediately sett it back..

```js
if (ampmEl.hasAttribute("class")) {
  ampmEl.removeAttribute("class");
}
ampmEl.setAttribute("class", "animateStart")
```

**A quick fix** would be to set a timeout to remove the class right after the animation is finished:

```js
function swapAMPM() {
  let value = ampmEl.innerHTML;
  ampmEl.classList.add("animateStart");
  setTimeout(() => { 
    ampmEl.classList.remove("animateStart") 
  }, 260)
  if (value === "AM") {
      value = "PM";
      ampmEl.innerHTML = value;
      console.log("Changed from AM");
  } else  {
    value = "AM";
    ampmEl.innerHTML = value;
    console.log("Changed from PM");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried from the very start, and each time I pressed the swap button, the animation time was reduced to nothing. I can't make sense of why though.. and should probably have saved the exact example before changing methods so I could replicate it.

Comment: I've checked it and it worked without any issues.. Though this was just a quick and not very reliable fix.. **r3wt** has definitely a solid solution.