# Javascript function works only one time

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, slideshow

I'm trying to create manual slideshow fo 5 slides. I created a function that works only once. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
 function n(){
    document.getElementById('sll').classList.add("slide-right");
}

 function p(){
    document.getElementById('sll').classList.remove("slide-right");
    document.getElementById('sll').classList.add("slide-left");
}
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="outer">
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right" onclick="n();"></i>
<div class="inner" id="sll">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
<i class="fas fa-arrow-left" onclick="p();"></i>
```

Comment: Could you add more details about how you are calling your `n()` and `p()` functions?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170892/javascript-add-remove-animation-class-only-animates-once

Answer (score 0):

For an automatic slide changer, try calling the function inside `setInterval()`: `setInterval(function() {p()},1000)`.
If you want it manual, you can try calling the function on button click using `document.getElementById('button').onclick = () => { p() }`